# How to make get request in HTMLOS HTTPS tag?

Tags: https, get

I am not sure how to place multiple header key in HTTPS Tag, the basic structure to make GET request in HTTPS Tage in HTMLOS is:

```
HTTPS( destination , maxsize , maxtime , method , postdata , header )
```

For example I need to put these 2 header in GET request:

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

and

```
X-Auth-Token: api-key your_api_key
```

I tried to join them using , and \n but didn't work as suggested by AI chatbots. Also not much resource available online.

Does anyone worked with it before and tell me how to get this done? Thanks in advance!

This is the only information I have:

Posts data to a URL and retrieves the HTML page from the URL and returns it. The header of the returned page is placed in TAGRESULTS.

If you are posting data that includes characters other than those used in URLs and file names then the data needs to be"encoded." Use the tag POSTPREP to prepare your postdata before transmission. (Internetworking Tag)

Usage HTTPS( destination , maxsize , maxtime , method , postdata , header )

Params
destination - the destination site's URL. Supports "https://". If the file is a startlink, then 'nosession' must be in the URL to get valid data returned.

maxsize - the maximum number of bytes to retrieve

maxtime - the maximum length of time (expressed in seconds) to allow for the retrieval of information

method - the HTTP protocol. Set to "GET", "POST" or "HEAD". If set to "HEAD" only the page header is returned.

postdata - data to send with page request. Leave empty if no data is being posted. Note: Method GET has a maximum character limit of 256.

header - HTTP header to send to the other server. Note: If you are using HTTPS with method POST to post data to a form be sure to add the header line Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded to the header. And if you are operating from a virtual hosting account, make sure to add the line Host: yourdomain.com to the header.

filename - the output file

Status
TAGRESULTS[1,1] - TRUE or FALSE
TAGRESULTS[1,2] - OK or error message

Network No

Example(s) yahoopage=HTTPS("yahoo.com","50000","15","GET","","")
IF TAGRESULTS[1,1] = "FALSE" THEN GOTO "badpage.html" /IF
DISPLAY LENGTH(yahoopage) /DISPLAY